# Call function that call ffmpeg in loop

Tags: shell, find, ffmpeg, function

I have function like this (got it form some website long ago):

```
function flv2mp3() {
    ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -acodec libmp3lame "$(echo -n "$1" | sed -e 's/\.[^\.]*$//').mp3"
}
```

and I'm trying to call that function in loop:

```
find . -name 'Rage*' -not -name '*.mp3' -print0 | \
while read -d '' -r file; do
   flv2mp3 "$file";
done
```

but got wierd result, it seems that it's after first invocation I 've got something like this:

```
stream #1:
  keyframe=1
  duration=0.023
  dts=94.923  pts=94.923
  size=388
stream #1:
  keyframe=1
  duration=0.023
  dts=94.946  pts=94.946
  size=381

Enter command: <target>|all <time>|-1 <command>[ <argument>]
```

and it waiting for input, what's going on? I can call flv2mp3 function without the loop just fine and it covert video to mp3.

I've also tried to put this:

```
flv2mp3 "$(echo -n $file | sed 's%./%%')"
```

because the files have `./` at the beginning but got the same results.

Comment: Is the `find` command finding the correct things? Try it by itself and change `-print0` to `-print`.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes it show correct files.

Comment: You may use `${1%.*}` to strip an extension off from the first command line argument.